# What are these mystery characters

Tags: java, text, character-encoding, mining

This might not be a programming question, but I could not find any answer for it on Google.

I have some text mining task and doing data cleaning at the moment.
I have come across some mystery characters far to often which are not in readable format.

These characters are: `&#x003b2` , `&#x00025` and so on.

All of these starts with a specific pattern and hence I believe they represent some encoding which is not readable to Excel.

Is there any way to convert them? I need to know what exactly these characters mean in order to know if I should remove them or not.

Comment: I think it's kind of encoding. What is the relationship between data mining task and the Excel? Bit unclear what you try to do.

Comment: I googled those codes and google told me what they were.... ? Did you try actually googling the codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are probably Unicode characters written as HTML entities in hexadecimal format.

- [`&#x003b2`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03b2/index.htm) is the "GREEK SMALL LETTER BETA" (β).
- [`&#x00025`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0025/index.htm) is the "PERCENT SIGN" (%).

Comment: I am not sure about Unicode ,but the percent sign and beta character makes perfect sense in my data since these characters are always after some numbers.

Answer (score 2):

They look like formatted hexadecimal values (possibly unicode if you're working with characters).
You may know them as `0x003B2` and `0x00025`, or many many other ways.